# android array in fragment giving null pointer

Tags: android, exception, pointers, android-fragments, null

from parent class

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArray("img_array", array);
                for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("this is from arrayy...."+array[i]);//this gives me value
                } 
 fragment = new Frag2 ();
             fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

this is target class

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {



     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                 ViewGroup containerObject,
                 Bundle savedInstanceState){
                 //here is your arguments
                 Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

                //here is your list array 
                String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("img_array");   
 System.out.println("this is len"+myStrings.length);//this STATMENT NOT WORKING
             }
        }
```

this is my logcat:

```
03-28 08:47:49.377: E/memtrack(24381): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-28 08:47:49.377: E/android.os.Debug(24381): failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-28 08:47:50.067: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:50.067: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:50.067: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:50.077: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:50.077: E/SurfaceFlinger(50): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -443628859
03-28 08:47:50.077: E/SurfaceFlinger(50): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
03-28 08:47:50.077: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:50.077: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.leeway.hdwallpapers/com.leeway.hdwallpapers.HD_Walllpaper_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at com.leeway.hdwallpapers.Frag2 .onCreateView(Frag2 .java:37)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-28 08:47:53.257: E/AndroidRuntime(24396):    ... 11 more
03-28 08:47:54.797: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.807: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.807: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.827: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.837: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.837: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.837: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.837: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.847: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-28 08:47:54.847: E/SoundPool(384): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
03-28 08:47:55.017: E/InputDispatcher(384): channel 'b53c0eb0 com.leeway.hdwallpapers/com.leeway.hdwallpapers.HD_Walllpaper_Activity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: please share the error message

Comment: i have added my logcat

Answer (score 0):

Don't put images in a bundle. Don't use System.out.println() either. Use the Logger.

In your code, whee is the img_array variable declared? Are you sure it is not null?

Comment: that is tagname and i am passing array named array.. that gives me value

Comment: Well, that array is certainly `null`. Debug your code to find out why.

Comment: and same array i am passing to target fragment

Comment: Then it is possible that the array is too big and can not be passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in onViewCreated

```
 @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 

                    //here is your list array 
                    String[] myStrings=bundle.getStringArray("img_array");   
     System.out.println("this is len"+myStrings.length);//this STATMENT N
    }
```